# Using switch case statement in a class

Tags: c++, class, switch-statement

Been struggling with this for a long time now:

I understand that switch-case statements must be acting on constant values, but by putting the statement in a class I thought I would be able to change the values (ie the 'constants') the statement acts on for two different callings of the class.

Inside my class, I have declared the constants which I need, but have not initialised them; I want to give them a value only when the class is instantiated, and so there will be two instances of the class both acting on the same switch-case statement but using different 'constant' integers.

Does this work out in c++?

Every time I try after having a sudden 'breakthrough' I get the error: 'Case value is not a constant expression', but surely if the method is a member of a class it can work on the constants assigned in its calling?

This is the relevant code:

*edit* so now I want to call SetValues1 for the instance 'FirstFourStrings' and for the switch-case to use the values set by this function (SetValues1); and to call SetValues2 for the second instance 'SecondTwoStrings' and let the switch case run using the values set byt this function **

```
class IDer{
public:

int ycounter = 0;

void SetValues1(){

    static constexpr int
    Ds = -11,
    D = -10,
    Cs = -9,
    C = -8,
    B = -7,
    As = -6,
    A = -5,
    Gs = -4,
    G = -3,
    Fs = -2,
    F = -1,
    E = 0;
}

void SetValues2() {
    static constexpr int
    Ds = 12,
    D = 13,
    Cs = 14,
    C = 15,
    B = 16,
    As = 17,
    A = 18,
    Gs = 19,
    G = 20,
    Fs = 21,
    F = 22,
    E = 23;
}

void IDmethod () {

    while (y <= ycounter){
    x = 0;
    while (x < Xrange){

        c = 7*y - x;

        switch (c) 
/* this switch-case statement needs to use values from SetValues1() in one instance and those from SetValues2() in the second instance */
        {
            case (Ds): case (Ds + 12): case (Ds + 24): case (Ds - 12): case (Ds - 24):
                Note = "Ds";
                break;

            case (D): case (D + 12): case (D + 24): case (D - 12): case (D - 24):
                Note = "D";
                break;

            case (Cs): case (Cs + 12): case (Cs + 24): case (Cs - 12): case (Cs - 24):
                Note = "Cs";
                break;

            case (C): case (C + 12): case (C + 24): case (C - 12): case (C - 24):
                Note = "C";
                break;

            case (B): case (B + 12): case (B + 24): case (B - 12): case (B - 24):
                Note = "B";
                break;

            case (As): case (As + 12): case (As + 24): case (As - 12): case (As - 24):
                Note = "As";
                break;

            case (A): case (A + 12): case (A + 24): case (A - 12): case (A - 24):
                Note = "A";
                break;

            case (Gs): case (Gs + 12): case (Gs + 24): case (Gs - 12): case (Gs - 24):
                Note = "Gs";
                break;

            case (G): case (G + 12): case (G + 24): case (G - 12): case (G - 24):
                Note = "G";
                break;

            case (Fs): case (Fs + 12): case (Fs + 24): case (Fs - 12): case (Fs - 24):
                Note = "Fs";
                break;

            case (F): case (F + 12): case (F + 24): case (F - 12): case (F - 24):
                Note = "F";
                break;

            case (E): case (E + 12): case (E + 24): case (E - 12): case (E - 24):
                Note = "E";
                break;
            }

        cout << " " << Note << " ";
        Note = "";

        x++;
        }

        cout << endl;
        cout << endl;

        y++;
        }
};

};

string Inputter(){
cout << "Enter chord (e.g. Gmajor, Gminor, Gsharpmajor, Gsharpminor)" << endl;
cin >> Input;
return Input;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    IDer FirstFourStrings;
    FirstFourStrings.ycounter = 3;
    FirstFourStrings.IDmethod();

    IDer SecondTwoStrings;
    SecondTwoStrings.ycounter = 5;
    SecondTwoStrings.IDmethod();


    Inputter();

}
```

Comment: The value after `case` must be an integer computable at compile-time . But you can use template parameters or the result of `constexpr` functions.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried. `static const` or (`static constexpr`) member variables should do the trick.

Comment: Just added the code after modifying it; if I pass the values from functions SetValues1 and SetValues2 to the main function 'IDmethod' using references, will the value be considered 'constant' and work with the switchcase?

Answer (score 2):

> I understand that switch-case statements must be acting on constant values

Correct

> but by putting the statement in a class I thought I would be able to change the values (ie the 'constants') the statement acts on for two different callings of the class.

No. 'Constant' means 'compile-time constant' in this context, and many others.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use the switch statement in the constructor, but you can have more than one constructor. You can add another variable to control which 'constant' integers you want to use. The extra variable is to decide which constructor is being called..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot initialise "constants" at when instantiating an object, simply because that violates the very definition of a constant, which must have a value at compile-time.

 
Assuming that all of the rest of your code is working as you want it to, you just want to use a regular variable where you are trying to use constants.